# syntax and methods for placing callbacks in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, callback

I have the following http endpoint in nodejs using the express library:

```
app.get("/api/stocks/lookup/:qry", function(req, res) {
    getJson(lookupSearch(req.params.qry), function(json) {
        var quotes = [];
        und.forEach(json, function(d) {
            getJson(quoteSearch(d.Symbol), function(j) {
                quotes.push(j);
            });
        });
        res.send(quotes);     //how can I make this execute after the .forEach is finished?
    });
});
```

Here, `getJson` looks like this:

```
var getJson = function(search, cb) {
    http.request(search, function(response) {
        var raw = '';
        response.on('data', function(d) {
            raw += d;
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
            cb(JSON.parse(raw));
        });
        response.on('error', function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }).end();
};
```

I see why this won't work as the http requests inside `getJson` are asynchronous and so `res.send(quotes)` will be sent back almost immediately. So, how can I get `res.send(quotes)` to be sent after the `forEach` loop is complete. Can I attach a callback onto a the `forEach` function?

In summary,

1. How can I use `res.send(quotes)` after the `forEach` loop is complete.
2. Is it possible to attach callbacks (such as a callback to be executed after the `forEach` loop) onto objects? What can I attach callbacks to? To be clear, the idea of a 'callback' to me means that the event loop will call it after the function/object in which the callback is attached to is finished executing.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting your getJson into a promise would be a good idea, as promises are nice to work with. Without the promises, the manual way is to keep a counter of outstanding requests:

```
var outstanding = 0;
json.forEach(function(d) {
    outstanding++;
    getJson(quoteSearch(d.Symbol), function(j) {
        quotes.push(j);
        if (!--outstanding) {
            res.send(quotes);
        }
    });
});
```

If you did go the promises way, you would make a `map` over `json`, and return the promise of the request; you could then specify a `then` over the array of promises. If you used jQuery instead of your own homebrew solution, for example,

```
var requests = json.map(function(d) {
    return $.getJSON(quoteSearch(d.Symbol), function(j) {
        quotes.push(j);
    });
});
$.when(requests).then(function() {
    res.send(quotes);
});
```

(untested code).

Comment: Can you give me a little bit of background about promises? Which library are they from?

Comment: Promises as such are a concept, and a [specification](https://promisesaplus.com/). Many libraries implement them; jQuery requests, for example, already comply with the specification, as demonstrated above. There are other libraries that do them, too, such as Q or async (pure promise libraries, so you would have to implement promisable in your `getJson`), or request-promise, a promise implementation for HTTP requests just like jQuery does.

Comment: The homebrew approach doesn't quite work. Wouldn't it usually be the case that `outstanding` will be `0` since you add 1 to it before each call `getJson` and then subtract 1 from it in `getJson's` callback?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: In a blocking world, it would, but we are dealing with callbacks here. Say ten requests get sent, `outstanding` is at `10`. Assuming the callback is called from an event listener, *no callbacks* can get executed while the loop is running, because JS is strictly single-threaded, so nothing interrupts our accumulation till `10`. When the function relinquishes the thread, responses start trickling in, and callbacks start getting called, dropping `outstanding`. As the the tenth response is processed, `outstanding` is finally back to zero and we have all the results.

Comment: It only works sometimes, as does a solution I crafted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774041/nodejs-expressjs-http-empty-server-reply. Perhaps it is not related to the asynchronous logic and instead the way I am using NodeJS.

Comment: I think I see: the above assumes no errors from the request. On an error, the counter does not get decremented, so it never reaches back to `0`. You need to decrement the counter both on `error` and on `end`. It should be the same problem in your linked question: the `length` idea is good, as long as each request pushes something into the `quotes` array, even if it is just `null`; but on `error`, you don't, so the `quotes` array stays short if an error occurs. Why you sometimes get errors from the server is another matter entirely.