# nodejs expressjs http empty server reply

Tags: node.js, http, asynchronous, express

I have the following backend http endpoint implemented with NodeJS and expressJS

```
app.get("/api/stocks/lookup/:qry", function(req, res) {
    getJson(lookupSearch(req.params.qry), function(json) {
        var quotes = [];
        und.forEach(json, function(d) {
            getJson(quoteSearch(d.Symbol), function(j) {
                quotes.push(j);
                if (json.length == quotes.length) {
                    res.send(quotes);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});

var getJson = function(search, cb) {
    http.request(search, function(response) {
        var raw = '';
        response.on('data', function(d) {
            raw += d;
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
            cb(JSON.parse(raw));
        });
        response.on('error', function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }).end();
};
```

What I do not understand is why this only works sometimes and why other times I get this error message from curl: `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` My solution that checks the lengths of `json` and `quotes` seems correct to me and so I think I must have misused some library. However, as I am new to asynchronous code (the http request in getJson) I am not 100% sure this is correct.

I asked a question with similar code here: [syntax and methods for placing callbacks in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772370/syntax-and-methods-for-placing-callbacks-in-nodejs) Note that the 'homebrewed' solution with incrementing and decrementing a count only works sometimes as well. I do not want to use JQuery inside node either.

- Why does the above http request only work sometimes?

Comment: Check if all the `j` are correct in the for loop. You are also sending the result only if `json.length == quotes.length`. I highly recommend you to learn about promises and Lo-Dash (check `reduce` for example): https://lodash.com/docs

Comment: `console.log(j)` in the loop gave me the results I expected. I only want to send the result when `quotes` has all the entries from `json` (quotes effective just adds attributes to each entry of `json`). What library should I use for promises in the backend? `und.forEach` is actually from lo-dash.